# Image in category of sets, existence of pushouts

Tags: category-theory

First question: According to definition from wikipedia: [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(category_theory))
What is $v$ in category $Set$?

Second question: Let $C$ be a category. Show that binary coproducts and coequalizers in $C$ exist of and only if there
exist pushouts. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Here's a hint. The coequalizer of $f,g:X\to Y$ acts like a quotient identifying the images of $f$ and $g$. The pushout $A\xleftarrow{f} X\xrightarrow{g} B$ is the same thing as the quotient of the coproduct $A+B/(\sim_{f,g})$. $v$ is the unique map you get once you specify $e', I'$, and $m'$ satisfying $m'e'=f$ in the diagram. It has nothing to do with the category of sets.